# OTK(Open Token) Vs JWT

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, token, websecurity, api-security

What is the purpose of Open token(OTK) and how is it different from JWT. I understand the technical implementation is different, but apart from that what is the difference in terms of usage. When to use a JWT and when to use an Open Token?

Comment: Use jwt, its simpler. And because its simpler, there is no need to use otk.

Comment: @webdeb, any particular scenario where OTK can be considered more beneficial?